# Windows 7 - How to restore a window that was on the second desktop (hdmi)

Tags: windows-7, windows, hdmi

I had to move a window to the right in order to display it on another monitor (smart tv), but once that i switch off the tv, i can't get that window anymore to drag it back to the main monitor.

All I can hope to do is to blindly move my cursor to the right and randomly try to click in order to drag it...

Been trying different stuffs, can't find how

ty !

Answer (score 0):

The Windows-P key combination is a shortcut for display switching. Hold the Windows key on your keyboard, hit P, and select 'Computer Only'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to select the window from the task bar, hold the `Windows` key and press the left or right `arrow key` to have the window snap to the edges of either screen.